# Data stores for aggregations of large number of objects identified by atttibutes

Tags: datastore

I have somewhat of an interesting problem, and I'm looking for data store solutions for efficient querying.

I have a large (1M+) number of business objects, and each object has a large number of attributes (on the order of 100). The attributes are relatively unstructured -- the system has thousands of possible attributes, their number grows over time, and each object has an arbitrary (e.g. sparse) subset of them.

I frequently have to perform the following operation: find all objects with some concrete set of attributes S and perform an aggregation on them. I never know S ahead of time, and so on every request I have to perform an expensive sweep of the database which doesn't scale.

What are some data store solutions for this kind of problem? One possible solution would be to have a data store that parallelizes the aggregations -- maybe Cassandra with Hive/Pig on top?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

At this point, Cassandra + Spark is a likely candidate.

In a pure Cassandra world, you could (in theory) create a manual mapping of all possible S attributes to data objects, and then load those in via app and process (where the name of the S attribute is the partition key, the value of the S attribute is the clustering key, and the data object ID itself is another clustering key, that way you can quickly iterate over all objects with S attribute set).

It's not incredibly sexy, but could be made to work.